# Can "applying a function for n times" be done using "exponentiating by squaring"?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Given a function of type `f :: a -> a`, we can produce a function that applies `f` for `n` times:

```
nTimes :: Int -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
nTimes 0 _ = id
nTimes 1 f = f
nTimes n f = f . nTimes (n-1) f
```

I can use [exponentiating by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) method here to implement another `nTimes` function:

```
nTimes' :: Int -> (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
nTimes' = nTimes'' id
    where
        nTimes'' acc n f
            | n == 0    = acc
            | even n    = nTimes'' acc (n `div` 2) (f . f)
            | otherwise = nTimes'' (acc . f) (n-1) f
```

My question is:

- Do `nTimes` and `nTimes'` always produce the same result?
- Will `nTimes'` be faster?

Comment: Just want to point out that this idea of "exponentiating by squaring" is already in standard library for all Monoid instances: check out the source code for `Data.Semigroup.stimesMonoid`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although they *are* equivalent, I would be extremely surprised if `ntimes'` were actually faster or memory-saving in any real situation. The problem is that unlike with the `x * x` doubling in ordinary exponentiation by squaring, `f . f` does not actually share any of the *real* work done when applying `f`. It is still going to turn in the end into applying the outermost single `f` to an argument constructed by all the remainder *somehow*. And `ntimes (n-1) f x` is going to be about the most compact representation you can have of that remainder until it is itself actually needed to be evaluated, which will require applying *its* leftmost `f` to a representation of `ntimes (n-2) f x`, etc.

EDIT: Let me add that this could change significantly if you were doing *memoization*, i.e. replacing `f . f` by `memo (f . f)` for some memo-combinator that modifies a function to remember its results. In that case actual work could be shared, and this version of `ntimes'` *might* sometimes be an improvement. Other times it could waste an awful lot of memory, though.

Answer (score 6):

It will produce the same result in both cases, because both `*` and `.` are associative operators.

However, the "speedup" is not the speedup you might be thinking of. Exponentiation by squaring is good because it decreases the number of times the `*` operator is applied, from linear to logarithmic number of times. In this case, you are decreasing the number of times the `.` operator is applied, from linear to logarithmic number of times.

However, like Ørjan Johansen said, unlike `*`, the `.` operator doesn't really do much -- it just takes two function values, and outputs a new function value, which essentially wraps the given two functions plus some code.

The resulting function that you get from `nTimes'`, when applied to a value, **must still run `f` n times**. Therefore, there is no improvement in actually *running* the resulting function, only an improvement in the process of *constructing* the resulting function using `.`.

Answer (score 4):

> Do nTimes and nTimes' always produce the same result?

Yes. (Unless you have bugs, didn’t check that).

> Will nTimes' be faster?

Probably not significantly . `f` itself is shared in both cases, so there is no recomputation there.

If `f` is not sufficiently lazy you are building a list of references to `f` vs. a tree with sharing of references to `f`, so you are saving a bit of memory here.

Comment: I think the list-building could be prevented by including the final argument of the function in the definition, i.e. `nTimes n f x = f (nTimes (n-1) f x)`.

Comment: I don’t think so, I think if `f` is strict it will still build a list (possibly on the stack). But it’s late, I might be wrong.

Comment: Right, although that's essentially the same as the difference between when you want `foldr` and `foldl'`, so you could write a similarly strict version of `nTimes` for that case.